# Flutter overlay with clickable background

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to position a widget on top of everything else.

I have this code working

```
PageRouteBuilder(
    opaque: false,
    barrierColor: Colors.transparent,  
    pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, __, _) {
      return Align(
        child: Container(
          width: 500,
          height: 500,
          color: Colors.black,             
        ),
      ); // Scaffold
    },
  ),
```

The problem is the barrier does not let click elements behind it. I can set dismissable to true or false, but even if false and `barrierColor: null`, elements behind the barrier are not clickable.

I am sure there must be an appropriate Widget for this, I add an image with example, I need to click the `Button 1`, `Button 2`, etc, when the overlay is visible.

I cannot use `Stack`

[image]

Comment: Your problem is not very clear. Can you add some visual to understand better?

Comment: @JigarPatel I have a horizontal menu bar on the top. I would like to be able to still click the menu items even when the Container added by the PageRouteBuilder is open. For reasons that are too long to explain, I need to use PageRouteBuilder

Answer (score 4):

Try wrapping `Align` with [IgnorePointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html) widget like so.

```
return IgnorePointer(
      child: Align(
        child: Container(
          width: 500,
          height: 500,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I added an image to exemplify

Comment: @JgarPatel I edited the whole question to make it more clear of what I need. Thank you

Comment: Did you try `IgnorePointer` as above?

Comment: yes, IgnorePointer makes ignore the pointer on the Container, not on the barrier, it is the opposite of what I need.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is OverlayEntry:

```
class OverlayWidget {
  static void show({@required BuildContext context, @required String message}) {
    OverlayEntry overlayEntry = new OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
      return Positioned(
          top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
          width: 500, 
          height: 500,
          child:  Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: 500,
                  height: 500,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
          ));
    });
    Overlay.of(context).insert(overlayEntry);

// remove entry whatever you want, in this case entry will be removed after 2sec
//    new Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)).then((value) {
//      overlayEntry.remove();
//    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This has the exact same problem

Comment: try again, i've modified the answer